# How to run Jmeter tests from bamboo?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, bamboo

How to run the Jmeter tests from bamboo? 
I tried in Jenkins which has the 'Execute windows batch command' option and I just pasted these lines and worked fine

```
jmeter -n -t C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\test.jmx
```

I need to work the same with bamboo as well. So I tried with the script task, selected Inline and in the script body I pasted the above lines
It failed with this error

```
/opt/bamboo/current/temp/TEST-NEW-NEW-33-ScriptBuildTask-6294682377804302931.sh: line 2: C:Jmeterapache-jmeter-2.13bin: command not found

/opt/bamboo/current/temp/TEST-NEW-NEW-33-ScriptBuildTask-6294682377804302931.sh: line 3: jmeter: command not found
```

I tried with the Command task also in bamboo but no luck.

I'm struggling how to run Jmeter tests from bamboo? Anyone please advise. I see that we can do it with maven I believe, but I don't know much about it, but if anyone has step by step instructions that I can follow that helps as well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Define the jmeter executable as a remote [capabiliety](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Configuring+remote+agent+capabilities+using+bamboo-capabilities.properties).

Then add a new command to your task and select jmeter as executable. Add your arguments and you are done.

Comment: Mine is local agent and not remote agent which is showing as default agent and I'm totally new to this bamboo and am learning as I go. How does this work with local agent? Please elaborate. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `/opt/bamboo/current/` looks pretty much like Linux path so consider other Bamboo step.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you need to either need to escape backslashes like:

```
C:\\apache-jmeter-2.13\\apache-jmeter-2.13\\bin\\test.jmx
```

or change them to forward slashes as:

```
C:/apache-jmeter-2.13/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/test.jmx
```

Other options on how to kick off a JMeter test from Bamboo build step are:

- [bamboo-jmeter-plugin](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/bamboo-jmeter-plugin)
- [JMeter Ant Task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/)
- [JMeter Maven Plugin](http://jmeter.lazerycode.com/)
- existing JMeter tests can be executed from Java code, moreover, it is possible to create a JMeter test purely in Java.

See [5 Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) guide for detailed information on aforementioned options.

Comment: I tried with forward slash and 2 backward slashed, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your Bamboo is in a linux environment.

From Bamboo on Linux, create a new **task** and select **script**:

```
cd /<your path>/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin
./jmeter -n -t <your path>/test.jmx
```

If Windows, set environment variable **JMETER_HOME** to C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\ and then on Bamboo's command line:

```
cd C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\ 
jmeter -n -t test.jmx
```